# Can you use jQuery( this ) and :after together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This doesn't work, but it shows you what I want to do:

```
$(this+":after").css('content', 'something');
```

Basically, I want my function to dynamically add an `:after` element to various matched elements.

Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: How come `this` are various matched elements?

Comment: You cannot select pseudo elements with jQuery or Javascript.

Comment: @MatthewL Really? You can't do `$("a:hover").css('color', '#F00');

Comment: @Alexander: this is the various matched elements. This line would be inside another function.

Comment: $(this) is a jQuery object and you cannot combine it with selectors or pseudo-selectors in that way.

Comment: The $('a:hover') would become an object @Emerson

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do?  You have complex selectors in jQuery for ancestors, siblings, descendants, etc.  There is an elegant solution to your problem, but more context is needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating CSS :before and :after pseudo-elements using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(this).after('content'); is what you're looking for

http://api.jquery.com/after/

Comment: This places the content after the element, but not within it, so it works completely differently from using an `:after` pseudo-element.

Comment: That is true, but it is unclear from the OP's statement exactly what he wants to do. If he wants it within the element we can cover that too.

Comment: I am trying to replicate the behavior of the css :after, so inside would be better. If it helps, what I'm actually trying to do is place the new element "behind" the original one.

Comment: $(this).appendTo('content'); will be what you want then as this applies the 'content' inside.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the pseudo-elements `:after` and `:before` in JavaScript (and jQuery is JavaScript, too!).

However, you can simply `.append()` something:

```
$(this).append('something');
```

If that's not what you want, you could put this in your CSS:

```
something:after { content: attr(data-after); }
```

Then you can use `.attr('data-after', 'whatever')` to modify the text used in the `:after` "element". Note that you cannot use `.data('after', 'whatever')` as it only *reads* attributes but never sets them.